# Magento product collection not filtering after being used in function

Tags: php, magento, collections, product

Ok, I have a fairly simple module running but I've come across an issue with product collections which I just can't solve. Here's the problem:

1) I load product collection based on a posted search category:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('search_category', array('eq' => $data['search_category']));
```

2) I use this collection in a basic function to retrieve attributes:

```
$section = $this->getSections($products);
```

3) Next in the code, I filter down the product collection further if another value is posted, and this runs another function.

```
if($data['section'] != "")
{
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('section', array('eq' => $data['section']));            
    $profile = $this->getProfiles($products);
    echo count($products);
    echo count($products->getIds());
}
```

Basically the products going into the second function are unfiltered. If I echo a count of the $products object at this stage it gives me the original amount in the product collection rather than the filtered amount.

If I echo $products->getIds() it gives me the correct filtered count.

I really can't understand why this won't work, I've checked the code in detail and it's all correct. It seems that if I use the product collection in a function, it cannot be filtered further.

If I move the filter above the first function it works, but it's obviously giving me the desired results.

Please help if anyone can explain this!

Answer (score 6):

You should check whether your `$products` collection is loaded somewhere between the initialization and the place where you're trying to add additional filter to it.

Because after the collection is loaded, the filter you apply to it would not affect it, since they only affect the final request to get collection from DB, and yours is loaded already.

The `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getAllIds()` (I believe you did misspell the `getAllIds()` mentioning `$products->getIds()`) will return the correct filtered amount though, because it will operate with the Select object inside the collection and make a request to DB instead of getting the Ids of loaded items.

Keep in mind, that basic functions like `count` and language constructions like `foreach()` will trigger the **load** process for collection.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks for your response. I will have a look at this further. My collection is loaded in a module, and the functions contain foreach loops.